# Determine the congruence class of $\ 5^{-3} \in \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have this question in my homework and I don't quite understand the notation.
Determine the congruence class of:
$$\bar5^{-3} \in \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$$

Any tips or hints on what's being asked or where to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$5^{-3} = (5^{-1})^3$.  So you need to find the inverse element of $5$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ and cube it.

This is easy to do with brute force, but if $\mathbb{Z}_p$ was considerably large, you would want to use the Euclidean algorithm to find the inverse of a given element.

Answer (score 1):

$$5 \equiv -2 \mod{7}$$
$$ 5^3 \equiv (-2)^3 \equiv -8 \equiv -1 \mod{7}$$
$$5^{-3} \equiv (-1)^{-1} \equiv -1 \mod 7$$